# A Javascript function has not the expected behavior

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

```js
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    session_start();
    // if Session is getting account_no then user can access index.php else require login
    if(isset($_SESSION["s_admin_id"]))
    {
        $Admin_id = $_SESSION["s_admin_id"];
        // For Getting Admin Details
        $query_admin = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_id=$Admin_id";
        $result_admin = mysqli_query($con, $query_admin);
        $row_admin_detail = mysqli_fetch_array($result_admin);

        // For Getting All Customers Details
        // $query_for_customer_details = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";
        // $customers_details = mysqli_query($con,$query_for_customer_details);
        // $row_customer_detail = mysqli_fetch_array($customers_details);

        // $no_of_customer
        $query_for_no_of_customer = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";
        $result_no_of_customer = mysqli_query($con,$query_for_no_of_customer);
        $no_of_customer = mysqli_num_rows($result_no_of_customer); 

        // $debit_count
        $query_for_debit_count = "SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction where trans_type='DEBIT'";
        $result_debit_count = mysqli_query($con,$query_for_debit_count);
        $debit_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_debit_count);

        // $credit_count
        $query_for_credit_count = "SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction where trans_type='CREDIT'";
        $result_credit_count = mysqli_query($con,$query_for_credit_count);
        $credit_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_credit_count); 

        // $total_bank_balance
        $query_for_total_bank_balance = "SELECT SUM(balance) as bank_balance FROM tbl_balance"; // SUM of all account balance
        $result_total_bank_balance = mysqli_query($con,$query_for_total_bank_balance);
        $array_total_bank_balance = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_total_bank_balance); # $no_of_transaction
        $total_bank_balance = $array_total_bank_balance['bank_balance'];

        // Start manage balance
        
        if(isset($_GET['operationType']))
        {
            $manage_account_no = $_GET['account_id'];
            $manage_amount = $_GET['amount'];
            $manage_oprationType = $_GET['operationType'];
            // Opeartion Credit
            if($manage_oprationType == "credit")
            {
                



                $Account_no = 338509629;
                        $query_for_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$Account_no";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
                $Amount = $manage_amount;
                $To_account = $manage_account_no;


                // if Account_bal is not Sufficient then Run This block Of code That disply You have not Sufficient bal or ben_account_no == logged_in usee then        Display You can not set    Your Account Number
                // else Run  Below Code
                if ($Amount > $Acount_bal)
                {
                    echo "You Have Not Sufficient Balance To Transfer";
                }
                else
                {
                
                    // 1. Reduce amount in Admin in customer
                    $Acount_bal = $Acount_bal - $Amount;
                    $query_for_update_from_Account_bal = "UPDATE tbl_balance SET balance=$Acount_bal WHERE account_no=$Account_no";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_update_from_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error ::   '.mysqli_error());
                
                
                
                    // 2. add amount in to_account customer
                    $To_account = $manage_account_no;
                    $query_for_Ben_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$To_account";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Ben_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
                
                    $Account_bal = $Acount_bal + $Amount;
                    $query_for_update_Ben_Account_bal = "UPDATE tbl_balance SET balance=$Account_bal WHERE  account_no=$To_account";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_update_Ben_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error ::    '.mysqli_error());
                
                
                
                    $Trans_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $Trans_type = "DEBIT";
                    $Purpose = "Operation made by Admin";
                    $To_account = $manage_account_no;
                
                    // $query_for_Account_no = "SELECT account_no FROM tbl_customer WHERE username='$Username'";
                    // $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Account_no) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                    // $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    // $Account_no = $row['account_no'];
                
                    $query_for_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$Account_no";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
                
                    // 3. insert transaction debit record for logged_in user in tbl_transaction
                    $query_debit_record = "INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (trans_date,amount,trans_type,purpose,   to_account,account_no,account_bal) 
                    VALUES ('$Trans_date', $Amount, '$Trans_type', '$Purpose', $To_account, $Account_no,    $Acount_bal)";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_debit_record) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                
                
                    $Trans_type = "CREDIT";
                    $query_for_Ben_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$To_account";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Ben_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
                
                    // 4. insert transaction credit record for to_account user in tbl_transaction
                    $query_credit_record = "INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (trans_date,amount,trans_type,purpose,  to_account,account_no,account_bal) 
                    VALUES ('$Trans_date', $Amount, '$Trans_type', '$Purpose', $Account_no, $To_account,    $Acount_bal)";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_credit_record) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                
                
                    if ($result)
                    {
                      echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">  
                      sweetAlertSuccess();
                     </script>' 
                      ;
                    }
                }
            
            }
        
        if($manage_oprationType == "debit")
        {
            $Account_no = $manage_account_no;
            $query_for_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$Account_no";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
            $Amount = $manage_amount;
            $To_account = 338509629;
            // if Account_bal is not Sufficient then Run This block Of code That disply You have not Sufficient bal or ben_account_no == logged_inusee then        Display You can not set    Your Account Number
            // else Run  Below Code
            if ($Amount > $Acount_bal)
            {
                echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">  
              notEnoughBal();
             </script>' 
              ;
            }
            else
            {
            
                // 1. Reduce amount in Customer Account
                $Acount_bal = $Acount_bal - $Amount;
                $query_for_update_from_Account_bal = "UPDATE tbl_balance SET balance=$Acount_bal WHERE account_no=$Account_no";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_update_from_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error ::   '.mysqli_error());
            
            
            
                // 2. add amount in Admin account
                $query_for_Ben_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$To_account";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Ben_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
            
                $Account_bal = $Acount_bal + $Amount;
                $query_for_update_Ben_Account_bal = "UPDATE tbl_balance SET balance=$Account_bal WHERE  account_no=$To_account";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_update_Ben_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error ::    '.mysqli_error());
            
            
            
                $Trans_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $Trans_type = "DEBIT";
                $Purpose = "Operation made by Admin";
            
                // $query_for_Account_no = "SELECT account_no FROM tbl_customer WHERE username='$Username'";
                // $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Account_no) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                // $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                // $Account_no = $row['account_no'];
            
                $query_for_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$Account_no";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
            
                // 3. insert transaction debit record for logged_in user in tbl_transaction
                $query_debit_record = "INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (trans_date,amount,trans_type,purpose,   to_account,account_no,account_bal) 
                VALUES ('$Trans_date', $Amount, '$Trans_type', '$Purpose', $To_account, $Account_no,    $Acount_bal)";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_debit_record) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
            
            
                $Trans_type = "CREDIT";
                $query_for_Ben_Account_bal = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_balance WHERE account_no=$To_account";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_for_Ben_Account_bal) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $Acount_bal = $row['balance'];
            
                // 4. insert transaction credit record for to_account user in tbl_transaction
                $query_credit_record = "INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (trans_date,amount,trans_type,purpose,  to_account,account_no,account_bal) 
                VALUES ('$Trans_date', $Amount, '$Trans_type', '$Purpose', $Account_no, $To_account,    $Acount_bal)";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_credit_record) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysqli_error());
            
            
                if ($result)
                {
                  echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">  
                  sweetAlertSuccess();
                 </script>' 
                  ;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    } else {
        header("location:http://localhost/online-banking/admin/dist/auth-login.php");
    }


?>
```

[image]greetings everyone, I am writing a project on online banking and I am stuck on its "add money" feature.

The add money button is working, but the problem is that it is not adding up the balance (even though I receive a notification so that it is added successfully). I have tried everything and since am a newbie in this I don't really know where the problem is coming from.

Here below is the part of the coding where it says add money but it is refusing to update balance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function alertifyPromptAdd(account_no)
  {
    function changeUrl(amount,operationType)
    {
        var url = new URL(window.location.href);
        var query_string = window.location.href;
        var search_params = new URLSearchParams(); 
        search_params.append('operationType',operationType);
        search_params.append('account_id', account_no);
        search_params.append('amount',amount);
        url.search = search_params.toString();
        var new_url = url.toString();
        window.location.href = new_url;
    };
    var amount = 0
    alertify.prompt(
        "Add Money",
        "1000",
        function(e, r) {
            alertify.success("Added : " + r);
            changeUrl(r,"credit");
        },
        
        function() {
          alertify.error("Cancel");
        },
      );
      
      
  }

  function alertifyPromptReduce(account_no)
  {
    function changeUrl(amount,operationType)
    {
        var url = new URL(window.location.href);
        var query_string = window.location.href;
        var search_params = new URLSearchParams(); 
        search_params.append('operationType',operationType);
        search_params.append('account_id', account_no);
        search_params.append('amount',amount);
        url.search = search_params.toString();
        var new_url = url.toString();
        window.location.href = new_url;
    };
    alertify.prompt(
        "Reduce Money",
        "1000",
        function(e, r) {
          alertify.success("Reduced : " + r);
          changeUrl(r,"debit");

        },
        function() {
          alertify.error("Cancel");
        }
      );
  }

  function sweetAlertSuccess()
  {
    Swal.fire({
      position: "top-end",
      icon: "success",
      title: "Money Successfully Transferred",
      showConfirmButton: !1,
      timer: 1500
    }); 
  }
  function notEnoughBal()
  {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Operation Failed",
      text: "Not Have Enough Balance !",
      icon: "error"
    });
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: please don't mistake java for javascript

Comment: which part of `function(e, r) { alertify.success("Added : " + r); changeUrl(r,"credit");}` do you think is adding anything to anything? ... oh, right , it's in `changeUrl`  ... but ... there's still nothing adding anything to anything else - is this supposed to be handled by server code maybe?

Comment: The code that you provided is only responsible for showing the notification. The adding of balance is probably performed on server side, and it would be interesting to be able to see the javascript code which performs the XMLHttpRequest to the API responsible to actually adding the balance. Then, in your browser inspector, you can check out the "Network" tab, to see whether the API is actually called, and if so, the response of this API route. This response will probably show useful information.

Comment: okay thanks i did that and i don't actually know what to do next so i shared screenshot and a new code. i will be awaiting your help on this